# CORS is giving error when tinymce is integrated with react application

Tags: reactjs

I have integrated tinymce with my React application. Everything is working fine but when I upload image CORS is giving following error:

plugin.min.js:9 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Javeria/Documents/react/moonleaks/backend/media/images/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

```
export default class App extends Component {

handleEditorChange = (e) => {
console.log('Content was updated:', e.target.getContent());
}



render() {
return (
<Editor
initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
init={{
plugins: 'link image code',
toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | 
code',

selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your html


images_upload_url:
'file:///C:/Users/Javeria/Documents/react/moonleaks/backend/media/images/',
images_upload_credentials: true
}}
onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
/>

);
}

Node server function:
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
cb(null, 'media/images')
},
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
cb(null, file.originalname)
}
});
const upload = multer({ storage })

app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    if (req.file)
    res.json({
    imageUrl: `images/${req.file.filename}`
    , file_size : req.file});
    else 
    res.status("409").json("No Files to Upload.");
    });
```

How can I correct this error?

Comment: <Editor /> is come from what library ?

Comment: import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly upload images to your system's drive folder, you have to implement an server which will recieve the image.

Replace the `images_upload_url` with the path on the server(can be running on your localhost).

Reference PHP file upload handler [Link](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/php-upload-handler/)

Comment: Yes, I have a node server which is running on url : http://localhost:4000. I also have image upload function in it which is working fine. You can have a look at the function as I have edited the code in above post.                                                                                                                                                                             But how can I use this function in tinymce?

Comment: then try changing `images_upload_url` to `localhost:4000/{path_of_upload_function}`

Comment: I tried using this path: http://localhost:4000/upload. Now it is giving 500 (Internal Server Error).  I used this function in some other place in this way:                          const uploaders = this.state.images.map(image => {
const data = new FormData();
data.append("image", image, image.name);                                    axios.post(BASE_URL + 'upload', data)})                                                                   here BASE_URL is 'http://localhost:4000/';

Comment: this means there is some error in server side code, try asking it in a different question and explain the error in detail.